19th century attitudes toward Dedekind's work and infinitary arguments
I was intrigued to come across the following statement made by Hilbert:

"In 1888, as a young private lecturer from Königsberg, I made a tour of the German universities. At my first stop, in Berlin, I heard in all mathematical circles, young and old, about the then just published work of Dedekind What are and what should the Numbers be? – mostly in an adversarial sense. The treatise is next to the study by Frege the most important first profound attempt at a foundation of elementary number theory. Around the same time, more than a generation ago, Kronecker clearly expressed a view and explained it with numerous examples, which today essentially coincides with our finitary attitude. Back then, we young mathematicians, private lecturers and students, made a sport of transferring proofs of mathematical theorems led by transfinite methods into the finitary, according to Kronecker’s model. Kronecker only made the mistake of declaring transfinite reasoning to be inadmissible."

(I encountered this quotation on page vi of Stefan Müller-Stach's new book "Richard Dedekind: What Are and What Should the Numbers Be? / Continuity and Irrational Numbers" (Springer-Verlag, 2024). Müller-Stach attributes the passage to page 487 of Hilbert's Die Grundlegung der elementaren Zahlentheorie, Math. Annalen, Band 104, 485–494 (1931).)
Two things surprised me about this passage.
First is the fact that Dedekind's book was not well-received when it was published; I'd like to know more about this.
Second is the way Hilbert describes a fashion (he calls it a "sport") of rewriting proofs to avoid use of infinitary methods. Who are the "young mathematicians" Hilbert is describing here, and what proofs is he alluding to? I have to say that this "sport" sounds to me very much the sort of thing that young twentieth-century mathematicians took up; I was very surprised to learn that it enjoyed a vogue in the late nineteenth century!

Two comments, by young mathematicians he says "we" (so Hilbert is included) and also he says "transfinite" not "infinitary".

""In 1888 I made a tour of the German universities. At my first stop, in Berlin, I heard in all mathematical circles, young and old, about the then just published work" Why do you read it as  "not well-received"?

Because the passage goes on to use the phrase “mostly in an adversarial sense”. I interpret this to mean that people were hostile toward the book. Am I mistaken? Perhaps someone who knows German could look at the original German text and see if I’ve misunderstood what Hilbert is saying here.

Hilbert discusses Berlin and not all of Germany here. Kronecker was one of the central figures of the Berlin school at the time, and his declared program was finitism. So the adversarial atmosphere in Berlin to Dedekind's ideas is unsurprising (nor was it specific to Dedekind. Kronecker also had adversarial disputes with Weierstrass (also Professor in Berlin) and Cantor). Compare e.g. Biermann "Leopold Kronecker" Complete Dictionary of Scientific Biography.

To answer the first question, Hilbert's text continues:

Kronecker machte nur den Fehler, die transfinite Schlußweise für unzulässig zu erklären. Er erließ Verbote gegen die transfinite Schlußweise, insbesondere sollte man nach ihm nicht schließen dürfen, daß, wenn eine Aussage $\mathfrak{U}(n)$ nicht für jede ganze Zahl $n$ zutrifft, es eine ganze Zahl $n$ geben müsse, für die jene Aussage falsch ist. Damals lehnte die ganze Mathematik einmütig seine
Verbote ab und ging über sie zur Tagesordnung über.

which Google translates as:

Kronecker only made the mistake of declaring the transfinite method of reasoning to be inadmissible. He issued prohibitions against the transfinite method of reasoning, in particular, according to him, one should not be allowed to conclude that if a statement $\mathfrak{U}(n)$  does not hold for every integer $n$, there must be an integer $n$ for which that statement is false. At that time, the whole of mathematics unanimously rejected his prohibitions and moved on with business as usual.

Original source found here: https://eudml.org/doc/159480 (p. 487).
